# Convert a sawtooth into a continuous linear function

Tags: python, signal-processing

Data from angular encoders is in a sawtooth shape ranging from 0° to 360°. I would now like to create a continuous linear function that describes the total angle.

I would like to go from a sawtooth function that can be created like this (in python with numpy):

```
x = np.arange(0,1000,2)
y = np.arange(0,1000,2)%360
```

[Plot sawtooth function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSVyU.png)

Back to the linear (in this case identity) function:

```
x = np.arange(0,1000,2)
y = np.arange(0,1000,2)
```

[Plot linear function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBJ7t.png)

The data I'm trying to use this on is not generated, it's measurement data from an angular encoder. I do not know the frequency. I know that the function value is in the interval [0,360]. I'm looking for a solution that can also handle a 'negative' sawtooth.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I faced your same issue and I solved it:

This is how my signal looks like:

[Sawtooth function of angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXye5.png)

It's an array containing the `Angle` of a rotating complex number in the range [-pi, pi].
What I wanted is the continuous linear function as you described.

I just thought to compare two consecutive elements of the array containing the angle values and exactly when the difference between them is a multiple of pi, each next value is incremented by such difference.

```
n=0
for i in range(len(Angle)-1):
     if round((Angle[i] - Angle[i+1])/pi) == n+2:
         n=n+2
     Angle[i+1]=Angle[i+1] + pi*n
```

This is what I got:

[Linear Angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEgLI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to split effective value in two parts, let's call them `base` and `reminder`. Total value would be `base + reminder`.
Then, you analyze changes of input and in case it was high (359 or close) and suddenly became low (0 or close), you add 360 to `base`. You subtract 360 from base if change happened in other direction. After `base` recalculation you assign input value to `reminder` for future reference. And that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, much appreciated thank you. I guess in this case I need to know if the sawtooth is falling or rising.

Comment: Exactly. You can conclude this by saving previous value(s) of input. If values received are rather continuous, it should be simple (as I explained in my answer). In other case you may need to use some more sophisticated techniques.